# Click Event Listeners while Re-Drawing Canvas

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, addeventlistener

I am building a javascript game dynamically rendered using canvas (at about 6FPS) in which I'd like to support clicking on various objects in the canvas to select them.

As a minimal example, I have a code example of a circle moving across the screen while binding a click event listener for the circle and un-binding the previous click event listeners (for a path that no longer exists after the canvas is cleared).

https://jsfiddle.net/gbvj67ro/7/

HTML

```
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

JS

```
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

function drawCircle(path2d, x, y, radius, fill) {
        ctx.beginPath();
        path2d.arc(x, y, radius, 0, 2*Math.PI);
        fill?ctx.fill(path2d):ctx.stroke(path2d);
        ctx.closePath();
    }

let eventListener = null
let i = 0

setInterval(function(){ 
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 1000, 200)
  
  // remove the existing event listener
  if (eventListener !== null) {
    canvas.removeEventListener("click", eventListener)
  }
  
  // new path
  let p1 = new Path2D();
    ctx.fillStyle = 'blue';
    drawCircle(p1, 20 + i, 20, 10, true)
    
  // new event listener function for current path
  eventListener = function(e) {
    if (ctx.isPointInPath(p1, e.offsetX, e.offsetY)) {
      console.log("clicked p1 i=" + i);
    }
  }
  
  // bind new event listener
  canvas.addEventListener("click", eventListener)    

  i += 5
  ctx.restore()
}, 1000);
```

Is this the best way to implement this? As an alternative, I could bind a single event listener that queries the current position of objects and whether they intersect with the click location. But this would require me to re-duplicate the scene drawing logic.

Comment: Are you in a position to cache the on-screen positions of the objects when you draw them? If so, you only need to run the logic once, but are able to access the results multiple times at virtually zero cost.

Comment: I have the positions of the objects. but then this requires me to perform a point-scene intersection logic to find whether the click point intersects any object position. It would be nicer if there was a way to dynamically track re-drawn canvas objects over time.

Comment: okay. I see no mention in your question or the code of making use of the browser's ability to do hit-testing. Is this something you've considered? If so, what makes it unsuitable? If you haven't considered it, perhaps you'll enjoy: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Hit_regions_and_accessibility